# autowire bean in StaticApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I am trying to autowire a bean in a StaticApplicationContext but although i can insert a bean and retrieve it successfully, I am not able to autowire it in another bean. Below is a simple example to explain what I mean.

In this example, the first assertion is successful, and the second one fails. Note that if I comment out the lines for this approach, and instead uncomment the lines for approach #2 that uses an AnnotationConfigApplicationContext the autowiring works. However I would like to make this work with StaticApplicationContext approach.

```
@Test
public void testAutowire() {

    //context configuration approach #1
    StaticApplicationContext context = new StaticApplicationContext();
    context.registerSingleton("child", Child.class);

    //context configuration approach #2
    //AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Child.class);

    Parent parent = new Parent();

    context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(parent);

    //this is successful
    Assert.notNull(context.getBean(Child.class), "no bean found");
    //this works only with AnnotationConfigApplicationContext and not with StaticApplicationContext
    Assert.notNull(parent.child, "no child autowired");
}

public static class Parent {

    @Autowired
    Child child;

    public Parent() {

    }
}

public static class Child {

    public Child() {
    }
}
```

Any ideas where the problem lies?

Comment: Try registering the parent too with the context.

Comment: I tried and it does not work with registering the parent. In fact I don't think it makes sense to do that, since I am manually creating the parent object outside the context. This is the reason I need to use the autowireBean method for performing the autowiring

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` internally registers an `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` bean to process `@Autowired` annotations. `StaticApplicationContext` does not.

You can add it yourself

```
context.registerSingleton("someName", AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class);
```

but you then need to `refresh` the `ApplicationContext`

```
context.refresh();
```

Comment: The documentation of `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` specifies that it also supports `@Value` by default. However, I was only able to get those annotations to work with `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`. This answer helped me get `@Autowired` working, but I am still curious about that. Is there another `BeanPostProcessor` necessary?

Comment: @scottyseus What kinds of values are you trying to inject through `@Value`? You'll need `PropertySources` for properties, maybe other things for other types.

Comment: I was receiving errors even when passing a literal value e.g. `@Value("some value")`. I don't have the exact error text now, but it was due to absent beans of type `java.lang.String`. If the `PropertySource` were the issue, the exception would be due to an unresolved placeholder